# DB2 auto increment changed by itself after restarted

Tags: sql, db2

Each time I restart my DB2 services, the auto increment field, always change by itself,
for example : before I restart, the auto increment value is at 13, and it's incremented by 1, and after I restart it's always become 31 and it's always incremented by 20
Any idea what may cause this?

Each time I restarted my Db2 service, I have to execute this command

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column> RESTART WITH 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 has a cache of generated values in order to reduce the overhead of generating values (Reduce the IO). This cache in memory, and assign the values as requested.

Take a look at the cache option when creating / altering the table. By default the cache value is 20.

It is important to understand how the sequeneces work in DB2. Sequences share many concepts with generated values / identity column.

- Create table http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html
- Alter table http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html
- Sequences http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0023175.html

Comment: I tried to alter the table using this function 
     ALTER TABLE INVENTORY ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 11 CACHE 1; 
But it seems not in the right format

Answer (score 0):

From [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp):

"Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated when a new record is inserted into a table."

This is the only thing you may expect: unique (=non-conflicting) numbers. How these are generated is left to the DBMS. You must not expect a number sequence without any gaps.

For instance, a DBMS might choose to "pre-allocate" blocks of ten numbers (23..32, 33..42, ...) for performance reasons, so that the auto-increment field must only be incremented for every (up to) ten records. If you have an `INSERT` statement that inserts only 5 records into a newly created table, it can "acquire a block of 10 numbers" (0..9), use the first five values (0..4) of it and leave the rest unused. By acquiring this one block of numbers, the counter was incremented from 0 to 10. So the next INSERT statement that fetches a block will get the numbers ranging from 10 to 19.